# i have select query with Group_ConCat Function?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have select query with Group_ConCat Function? Now the Problem is that ID Not Showing On The Page
after echo the row?

```
<?php 
$querypid=mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM products ORDER BY id") or die("PID  Query");
$rowpid=mysql_fetch_array($querypid); 
echo $ids=$rowpid['0'];
?>
```

I want to use that id in

```
header("location:registration.php?id=$ids");
```

now how can i get one by one id?

Comment: @DreamEater it is showing like this mydomain.com/test.php?id=7,8,10,11,12?

Comment: erm, `GROUP_CONCAT` by default concatenates all values with a `,`(comma). That is the output you'll get.

Comment: @DreamEater can i get one by one id??

Comment: Provide a little more code.

Comment: i want to use that id in header("location:registration.php?id=$ids"); now how can i get one by one id?

Comment: header can use only one value at a time.

Comment: @DreamEater do you any another option?

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding of your code, you are redirecting to a page with the URL being like this:

> http://example.com/registration.php?id=1,2,3,4,5

If that's the case, then `registration.php` can simply use this:

```
$idlist = explode(",",$_GET['id']);
```

This will result in an array, with each item being one of the IDs. You can then iterate through them with a `foreach(){}` loop.